# Concatenate variable instead of overwriting using mexPutVariable

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want my array to be concatenated to a variable with a specific name from a cmex sfunction instead of being overwritten using mexPutVariable. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to read the current value, concatenate the new data, then write to the variable.

Comment: I was thinking this too, maybe I'll take this approach. Thanks for the suggestion @CrisLuengo :)!